# Custom claim not accessible in AuthorizationHandlerContext Identity server 4 JWT

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a profile service that adds the claim to the token

**Profile service**

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);

            var claims = new List<Claim>();

            var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
            foreach (var userClaim in userClaims)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(userClaim.Type, userClaim.Value));
            }

            context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
        }
```

**JWT Token**

```
{
  "nbf": 1608909669,
  "exp": 1608996069,
  "iss": "https://localhost:5001",
  "aud": "https://localhost:5001/resources",
  "client_id": "Local",
  "sub": "307f4f24-71a5-4aee-8505-f87b58a1eb2e",
  "auth_time": 1608908167,
  "idp": "local",
  "IdentityServer": [
    "Read",
    "Create",
    "Update",
    "Delete"
  ],
  "Product": [
    "Read",
    "Create",
    "Update",
    "Delete"
  ],
  "jti": "87FA14C0153AD10D0E16A721720D19DB",
  "sid": "C739A377659C364AA29040FEE2FB4FA2",
  "iat": 1608909669,
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

Only able to get the below claim in the **AuthorizationHandlerContext**

[image]

**StartUp.cs**

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                // base-address of your identityserver
                options.Authority = configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:OAuth:AuthorizationUrl").Value;

                // name of the API resource
                options.ApiName = AuthorizePolicy.apiScope;
            });


app.UseAuthentication();
```

Why I am not able to access `IdentityServer , Product` claim. I am using Identity server 4 latest version

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

While adding the below code during the login process in the Account controller

```
            var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
            var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();

            var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.Id)
            {
                DisplayName = user.UserName,
                AdditionalClaims = claims    
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, props);
```

Now the user contains all the additional claims, but if I remove one of the claims the JWT token is refreshed, however, the User Identity still contains the old value, to refresh the identity I need to explicitly login the user again which is not suitable, how can I fixed this ?

Comment: Have you checked all the claims in the ClaimsIdentity as well ?

Comment: @CeemahFour yes I checked still same claims. please find the image above

Comment: @CeemahFour - Any idea what I am missing, I am using Identity server latest version with SQL server. Do I need to do something somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

by default custom claims will not be included in the User, instead you need to manually map the incoming claims that you care about.

Typically, you would add this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // By default, Microsoft has some legacy claim mapping that converts
    // standard JWT claims into proprietary ones. This removes those mappings.
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

and then in the AddOpenIDConnect options, set:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("website", "website");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("gender", "gender");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("birthdate", "birthdate");
```

alternatively

```
options.ClaimActions.MapAllExcept("iss", "nbf", "exp", "aud", "nonce");
```

Same configuration could look like this:

```
 }).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:6001";
                options.ClientId = "authcodeflowclient";
                options.ClientSecret = "mysecret";
                options.ResponseType = "code";

                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("employee_info");

                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("employment_start", "employment_start");
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("seniority", "seniority");
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("contractor", "contractor");
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("employee", "employee");
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("management", "management");
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey(JwtClaimTypes.Role, JwtClaimTypes.Role);

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/";
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                    RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,

                };

                options.Prompt = "consent";
            });
```

If you don't want to deal with the tokens and add the claims there, then an alternative is to lookup additional user details in your authorization polices.
See this page about [Custom Authorization Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for more details.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I don't have AddOpenIDConnect options. How can I added ?

Comment: Are you protecting an API or a client? See https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html , the concept of claims mapping is the same for both clients and APIs

Comment: Yes I am protecting the API, I already have that code above, but in the Option I didn't found ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey() method

Comment: I have never used AddIdentityServerAuthentication(), instead I use AddOpenIDConnect and AddJwtBearer to protect my client and APIs.  see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_aspnetcore_and_apis.html?highlight=addopenidconnect  and https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html?highlight=addjwtbearer#supporting-both-jwts-and-reference-tokens

Comment: Can you please have a look on my code, here is the repo - https://github.com/anandjaisy/IdentityServer/tree/feature/sociallogin/Falcon-Identity

Comment: Hard to tell, but the general rule for dealing with IdentityServer is to put IdentityServer, Client and your API on separate services otherwise its hard to follow and troubleshoot when things goes wrong. You would use AddOpenIDConnect  in the client application and AddJwtBearer to protect the API.

Comment: I have resolved that issue, albeit having another issue, updated question in UPDATE 1 text block of the code, can you please have a look.

Comment: I think doing a silent SignInAsync is required to update the tokens in the session cookie. The alternative is to store the tokens separately, in some cache of some sort. (TokenStore)

Comment: I added some more details a the end of my answer