# Adding claims with profile service in Identity server causing looping in the authentication process

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a custom Profile service to add the claim to the access_token as below

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> _claimsFactory;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
        }

        public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        
        var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
        foreach(var userClaim in userClaims)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(userClaim.Type, userClaim.Value));
        }
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
        }

        public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
            context.IsActive = user != null;
        }
    }
```

With the below code I am registering the profile server in Identity server 4/4.1.1

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
                }) .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
```

When I register a `ProfileService` the UI is looping, I am using PCKE with authorization flow.If I remove the `ProfileService` everything works fine.

I need the profile service because I am adding a custom claim to the `access_token`

app.UseRouting();

```
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
```

Comment: Can you try if it helps if you call `context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);` in your GetProfileDataAsync? My guess is that there is something missing on the claims that is used for keeping track of the login process. If this helps you should be able to debug and find the problematic claim.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what the what you mean by "looping" ?

Comment: @CeemahFour - When I log in to the Identity server, the login is successful, however, it should return to the calling application, but UI looping on this call https://localhost:5001/auth-callback?code=CFF84696FD05C224606FC5A4A49EC5B54AAA2C030630C9270F168D433ECFC7B4&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=3305f5045e1d40d9ae64648967bc584a&session_state=eXxCn9Ev-2x0IVBp6wy7LuRCZueXmubUyqjibG1V4G8.342F40EFD439DAC040C551CA738E8894

Comment: @CeemahFour it going to infinite loop and calling the method GetProfileDataAsync of profile service everytime

Comment: @SanJaisy I've tried this locally, and I don't run into the loop. the two differences in my setup are: I don't use ```.AddProfileService``` but instead inject profile service as an ```services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>(); ```.

Comment: @CeemahFour - I have an Angular application calling Identity server, after login it does happens, if I remove AddProfileService, everything works

Comment: @SanJaisy one additional this - I could be wrong here, but I don't see why you would need to call the userManager.GetClaims again. the principal you created should come with a superset of all claims. The next statement is basically, removing the extra ones and only letting through the requested ones. So Is there a specific reason, why you add them back? If you really want all the claims to go through, then remove the line which filters on requested claims? I realise this isn't related to the question, but seemed counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: @CeemahFour - I did remove that one

Comment: @CeemahFour now that issue has been resolve, but facing the new issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449615/custom-claim-not-accessible-in-authorizationhandlercontext-identity-server-4-jwt

Comment: @Compufreak facing the another issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449615/custom-claim-not-accessible-in-authorizationhandlercontext-identity-server-4-jwt

Comment: @SanJaisy curious how you resolved the looping issue

Comment: @CeemahFour - I need to add a sub claim and it worked. Can you please help me with the new issue I am facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449615/custom-claim-not-accessible-in-authorizationhandlercontext-identity-server-4-jwt

Answer (score 2):

One thing is that you should not add app.UseAuthentication(); in your startup class, instead it should look like this:

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();

UseIdentityServer adds UseAthentication when called, so no need to call it twice.

Comment: Thank you, can you please help me with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449615/custom-claim-not-accessible-in-authorizationhandlercontext-identity-server-4-jwt